# Call webservice located on external server, from dialogflow webhook agent

Tags: web-services, call, external, webhooks, dialogflow-es

We are testing the dialogflow platform, and would like to call a external webservice located in our servers to retrieve live data from a legacy system.

We would like to host all process logic in our server, to minimize communication issues and others, instead of using other platforms like heroku, slak, etc.

We are trying to test this sequence, but have no success:
- created a simple dialogflow agent, that asks some variables
- in the end, we activated the webhook fulfillment to call our webservice
- mapped our webservice in the fulfillment area without authentication
- in our server, started a simple node.js listener to log any https requests to allow better understanding of variables/sequence required by dialogflow

We can't detect any https calls from dialogflow: when we test our agent inside dialogflow, it seems that never calls our webservice (we see no https call logs). Are we missing any step to force dialogflow to call our webservice? Is there any example (node.js, c#, etc) that we can host in our server and use it has a starting example?

Comment: Can you update your question to include a screen shot of the Fulfillment screen (masking any sensitive information, such as the hostname) and of the entire Welcome Intent screen?

Comment: Are you using Firebase functions for fulfillment?  Firebase requires billing to be enabled for external HTTP/S calls from the Firebase function.

Comment: Hi Prisoner, the fulfillment screen just has our https url, with no basic auth or headers, has defined in the webhook fulfillment example link. My welcome intent screen is a standard one, with just a default text response.

Comment: Hi matthewayne, we are not using Firebase functions. We thought fulfillment is able to call any external system, according with [fulfillment example](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment#webhook-example). We are using a free google account, and maybe this is the problem. We will check it.